# MySQL for ToDo lists?

Tags: mysql

I regularly have lists such as "To-do" and "Done-works". It would be useful if it worked something like:

> mysql add-to-column-in-table "Blog
> corrected"
>
> mysql read-column-in-table-where-match-blog "Blog"

Can I use MySQL for the job? Are you using it for day-to-day things?

**[Clarification]** I need to organize my things to tables. I have over thirty dirrerent To-Do lists alone. They have different relations to other lists. They are cumbersome to organise, and some lists tend to get old.

A reason for the question is that I am unsure of the configuration on Ubuntu. There are too many mysql-files, such as "mysql-admin" and "mysql-common". I need some simple package that is easy-to-use and easy-to-get-started. It should work only locally.

Comment: you're not thinking in a sql-like manner. your columns aren't the items, your column are "item-name", and 'item-state." A database table isn't exactly the same as a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I actually understand your question. Would you be able to clarify it?

You certainly can use mysql (or any database) to make a todo list. At one end of the spectrum, you could make it a single table, with two fields:

```
todo (id, description)
```

And just add and delete from the list as you go:

```
INSERT INTO `todo` (`description`) VALUES ('buy milk');
DELETE FROM `todo` WHERE `id` = 3;
```

You could then add some flags so you can track items after they're completed:

```
todo (id, description, isDone)    -- isDone would be a 0 or 1
```

And then to find all your todos:

```
SELECT description FROM todo WHERE isDone = 0;
```

You could continually add new features to it, like dates, categories, urgency levels, tasks and subtasks (eg: Make Breakfast could have subtasks of "Buy milk", "Toast bread" ...), etc etc. Just choose what's appropriate for your needs. In any case, MySQL will have you covered.

Ps: Don't forget the power of Notepad for these tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use MySQL or better yet you could use SQLite3 (you won't need to run a process and its fast).

If all you want is a text-based todo list you can run on the command-line I'd check out Gina Trapani's [todo.txt](http://ginatrapani.github.com/todo.txt-cli/).  You'd get most of the benefits of a querying a database but with a nice CLI that's optimized for todo related activities (querying dates, contexts, etc.)